# TypeError: 'MapResult' object is not iterable using pathos.multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, pathos

I'm running a spell correction function on a dataset I have. I used `from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool` to do the job. Once the processing is done, I'd like to actually access the results. Here is my code:

```
import codecs
import nltk

from textblob import TextBlob
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
from pathos.multiprocessing import ProcessingPool as Pool

class SpellCorrect():

    def load_data(self, path_1):
        with codecs.open(path_1, "r", "utf-8") as file:
            data = file.read()
        return sent_tokenize(data)

    def correct_spelling(self, data):
        data = TextBlob(data)
        return str(data.correct())

    def run_clean(self, path_1):
        pool = Pool()
        data = self.load_data(path_1)
        return pool.amap(self.correct_spelling, data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    path_1 = "../Data/training_data/training_corpus.txt"
    SpellCorrect = SpellCorrect()
    result = SpellCorrect.run_clean(path_1)
    print(result)
    result = " ".join(temp for temp in result)
    with codecs.open("../Data/training_data/training_data_spell_corrected.txt", "a", "utf-8") as file:
        file.write(result)
```

If you look at the main block, when I do `print(result)` I get an object of type `<multiprocess.pool.MapResult object at 0x1a25519f28>`.

I try to access the results with `result = " ".join(temp for temp in result)`, but then I get the following error `TypeError: 'MapResult' object is not iterable`. I've tried typecasting it to a list `list(result)`, but still the same error. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you need to do `result =  SpellCorrect.run_clean(path_1).get()` (note `.get()`). I'm guessing the `a` means "async" though, so you'll likely need to make sure the results are ready first. See the [docs](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pathos/latest/pathos.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply @Carcigenicate, I meant to use map instead of amap (my bad). Regardless, I've used the .get() as suggested and I now get the following error: 

_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.SpellCorrect'>: it's not the same object as __main__.SpellCorrect

Comment: Try changing `SpellCorrect = SpellCorrect()` to `spellcorrect = SpellCorrect()`. In other words, disambiguate the Class (`SpellCorrect`) from the instance (`spellcorrect`).  You'll then need to change `result = SpellCorrect.run_clean(path_1)` to `result = spellcorrect.run_clean(path_1)` since it is the instance which calls the method, not the class.

Comment: I'm the `pathos` author.  As @Carcigenicate says, use `map` (or `imap`), not `amap`.  Only use `amap` if you want to a non-blocking non-iterable.  Also, it's good advice from @unutbu, but I have one nit... `pathos` can store more than a reference to the class, as it uses `dill` for serialization, and not `pickle`, and thus can store the actual class object.

Comment: @MikeMcKerns: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: unutbu & @MikeMcKerns, thank you so much for the reply. All good now and a nice learning experience from the both of you. Just one last question, I had a look at the documentation and it says in the typical examples that the number of default nodes set to ProcessPool(nodes=x) is 4. Is 4 the default value or does it use all the cores I have if I don't declare a set value? Sorry for the silly question

Comment: @Sam: the default is the number of processors you have.  If it says otherwise it the documentation, please report that as an issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 5):

The `multiprocess.pool.MapResult` object is not iterable as it is inherited from [AsyncResult](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/parallel/parallel_details.html#AsyncResult) and has ***only*** the following methods:

- **wait([timeout])**
  Wait until the result is available or until timeout seconds pass. This method always returns None.
- **ready()** Return whether the call has completed.
- **successful()** Return whether the call completed without raising an
  exception. Will raise AssertionError if the result is not ready.
- **get([timeout])** Return the result when it arrives. If timeout is not
  None and the result does not arrive within timeout seconds then
  TimeoutError is raised. If the remote call raised an exception then
  that exception will be reraised as a RemoteError by get().

You can check the examples how to use the get() function here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, TimeoutError
import time
import os

def f(x):
    return x*x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = Pool(processes=4)              # start 4 worker processes

    # print "[0, 1, 4,..., 81]"
    print pool.map(f, range(10))

    # print same numbers in arbitrary order
    for i in pool.imap_unordered(f, range(10)):
        print i

    # evaluate "f(20)" asynchronously
    res = pool.apply_async(f, (20,))      # runs in *only* one process
    print res.get(timeout=1)              # prints "400"

    # evaluate "os.getpid()" asynchronously
    res = pool.apply_async(os.getpid, ()) # runs in *only* one process
    print res.get(timeout=1)              # prints the PID of that process

    # launching multiple evaluations asynchronously *may* use more processes
    multiple_results = [pool.apply_async(os.getpid, ()) for i in range(4)]
    print [res.get(timeout=1) for res in multiple_results]

    # make a single worker sleep for 10 secs
    res = pool.apply_async(time.sleep, (10,))
    try:
        print res.get(timeout=1)
    except TimeoutError:
        print "We lacked patience and got a multiprocessing.TimeoutError"
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been a long time, but MapResult has a `_number_left` property:

```
data = p.amap(...)

while not data.ready():
    print(data._number_left)
```